# How to check for conflicting dates in a form using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a form that dynamically generates rows with form controls. Each row contains inputs and select elements like below:

```
<input type="date" name="from_a[]"  class="from_a" />
<input type="date" name="till_b[]"  class="till_b" />
<select name="category_c[]" class="category_c" >...</select>
<select name="item_d[]" class="item_d" >...</select>
```

Using JQuery, I need to make sure that if multiple rows have the same category+item selected, they don't have conflicting **from** and **to dates**.

For example, the following data should show an error with category+item as error details since row 1, row 3 and row 4 have conflicting from / to dates:

```
| 2022-06-03 | 2022-06-10 | a | b |
| 2022-06-03 | 2022-06-12 | c | d |
| 2022-06-05 | 2022-06-13 | a | b |
| 2022-06-01 | 2022-06-08 | a | b |
| 2022-06-15 | 2022-06-20 | a | b |
| 2022-06-02 | 2022-06-10 | a | e |
```

Please help how this can be achieved?

Comment: You'll need to iterate over the list, checking if any start or end date is between the start and end date of any other item.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to to check for conflicting dates you can try example of me, hope to help you !

```js
const data = [
  { start : '2022-06-03', end: '2022-06-10', item1: 'a', item2: 'b' },
  { start : '2022-06-03', end: '2022-06-12', item1: 'c', item2: 'd' },
  { start : '2022-06-05', end: '2022-06-13', item1: 'a', item2: 'b' },
  { start : '2022-06-01', end: '2022-06-08', item1: 'a', item2: 'b' },
  { start : '2022-06-15', end: '2022-06-20', item1: 'a', item2: 'b' },
  { start : '2022-06-02', end: '2022-06-10', item1: 'a', item2: 'e' }
]
let temArr = [...data]
const errors = data.reduce((res, ele) => {
  let others = temArr.filter(other => other.start < ele.end && other.end > ele.start && other.item1 === ele.item1 && other.item2 === ele.item2)
  temArr = temArr.filter(other => !(other.start < ele.end && other.end > ele.start && other.item1 === ele.item1 && other.item2 === ele.item2))
  return others && others.length > 1 ? [...res, others] : res
}, [])
console.log(errors)
```